# Brezis excercise 4.3.1. If $f$ and $g$ are in $L^p(\Omega)$, then $h = max\{f(x),g(x)\}$ is in $L_p(\Omega)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Given two functions $f,g\in L_p(\Omega)$, define $h(x)=max\{f(x),g(x)\}$. Prove that $h\in L_p(\Omega)$.

I know that $|h(x)|^p\geq |f(x)|^p$ and $|h(x)|^p\geq |g(x)|^p$ but this seems to go nowhere... any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: for all $x\in\Omega$, the following inequalities hold:
$$
\left\lvert h(x)\right\rvert^p\leqslant \max\left\{\left\lvert f(x)\right\rvert^p,\left\lvert g(x)\right\rvert^p\right\}\leqslant \left\lvert f(x)\right\rvert^p+\left\lvert g(x)\right\rvert^p.
$$